# how to add variable values in link using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

how can i get the variable (cnt) number in that link

```
$('#page_navigation').append("<ul class='pagination'></ul>");
$(".pagination").append("<li>" + '<a href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>'+"</li>");
  for (cnt = 1; cnt <= number_of_pages; cnt++) {
  $(".pagination").append("<li>"+'<a href="Index?p=&cnt">' + cnt +'</a>'+ "</li>");
}
```

i want to get that links like Index?p=1,Index?p=2 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variables value in to the link. Try this:

```
$(".pagination").append('<li><a href="Index?p=&' + cnt + '">' + cnt +'</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create element using jQuery way

```
var anchor = $('<a></a>', {
    text: cnt,
    href: "Index?p=&" + cnt
});
var li = $('<li></li').append(anchor);
$(".pagination").append(li);
```